# Unable to share singleton instance in multiple jars ran on single machine

Tags: java, jar, jvm, singleton

I am bit confused now, I have 4 java coded jars that should share same instance of a class over them.
I have implemented "Bill Pugh Singleton Implementation" in my code.
Problem is when i run these jars they show that they have different instance of singleton class. Jars that are run on a single machine have their own JVM loaded or what? below is what i implemented.

```
public class MyProducer implements ProducerInterface{

    private static KafkaProducer<String, byte[]> producer; // this variable should be shared among all jars.....

    private MyProducer () {
        logger.warn("Producer is called now.........");
        setProducerConfigurations();

    }

    public static Producer getInstance(){

        return SingletonProducer.INSTANCE;
    }

    private static class SingletonProducer{
        private static final MyProducer INSTANCE = new MyProducer ();
    }
}
```

Now the classes that use have code like this:

```
public class MyProcessThread extends ProcessThread {
    public static ProducerInterface producer;

    @Override
    public void run() {


            if(producer==null){

                producer= MyProducer .getInstance();
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: You decide how many JVM are run. Every time you start a new process you have a new copy of the classes and singletons. If you want them to share objects, run them all in the same JVM.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the four jars using four different java commands then this will setup four different Java Virtual Machines (JVM) in your machine: the singleton is unique within each JVM (without considering classloader setup that may complicate the topic).

Comment: yes, i am using java -jar for each jar to run. if that is the case what is the best approach now. how i can share them, OSGI cannot be the option in our case as it came up with numerous issues of libraries resolution first.

Comment: It really depends on your use case; is it possible for you to run one java command with all the 4 jars in its classpath?

Comment: what you mean please elaborate or give example.

Comment: something like: `java -classpath jar1.jar:jar2.jar:jar3.jar:jar4.jar MainClass` where the four jars in the current folder and MainClass is a class within one of them that contains the main method that starts the application.

Comment: these 4 jars are all run-able jars, and all have main method.

Comment: Then if you want to expose a single instance of your producer to be available for all processes you'll have to use some form of inter-process communication. However, that's not trivial, probably you may want to reconsider the current design.

Answer (score 0):

> these 4 jars are all run-able jars, and all have main method.

If you want to use a singleton you have to run them in the same JVM. Write a wrapper `main` calling the mains of each jar. In separate threads if necessary.